# Concise/elegant method for duplicating a table's schema?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a table T1 with an arbitrary schema.  I'd like to create a second table T2 with the same schema, then port some data from T1 into T2.  I can create T2 (with the identical column names and types) manually easily enough, but it's not an elegant solution.

I'm new to working with ADO.net, and just discovered the `SqlDataAdapter` class, which I can use to extract a `DataTable` containing a `DataColumnCollection`.  If possible, I'd like to somehow use this `DataColumnCollection` directly to define a new table, kinda this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table2", originalDataColumnCollection);
sqlDataAdapter.MakeTable(dt);
```

Is there an API that enables this easily?  My current method involves iterating over `originalDataColumnCollection` to build the `create table Table2 (...)` string, then submitting that via `SqlCommand`.

**Update:**

I just noticed that I can't get the SQL type from `originalDataColumnCollection`, but instead if gives me back a C# type.  Maybe this method won't work at all for ensuring an identical column structure?

Comment: select * from old_table into new_table where (rows you want to import)

Comment: @dotctor I don't want to copy the rows (yet; I need to do some client-side processing).  I'm trying to create a new (empty) table with the same column names and types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute an empty select command and store it to a new table so a table is created with the same schema as the old table and you can do what you want later with it.

```
select * into new_table from old_table where 1 = 0
```

executing this sql command will create an empty table with the same schema as the table you want.

Comment: Cool; I didn't know you could create a table that way.  I'm getting a syntax error "near the keyword 'into'" when I try to run that, though.

Comment: I think it should be `select * into new_table from old_table where 1 = 0`.

Comment: Thanks, and get some sleep! :)